# How to change the buttons order in QMessageBox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qmessagebox

The code creates a `QDialog` window with a single `QPushButton`. Clicking the button brings up the `QMessageBox` window with three buttons. Is there a way to re-arrange the buttons order?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(300, 100)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Submit')
        button.clicked.connect(self.onclick)
        self.layout().addWidget(button)

    def onclick(self):
        self.close()
        messagebox = QtGui.QMessageBox(QtGui.QMessageBox.Warning, "Title text", "body text", buttons = QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok |  QtGui.QMessageBox.No |  QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel, parent=self)
        messagebox.setDefaultButton(QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        exe = messagebox.exec_()
        print exe

dialog = Dialog()
dialog.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QMessageBox.addButton()` overload can be used for button ordering. The default ordering varies according to the platform. Use `QMessageBox.clickedButton()` after calling exec() to query what button was used.

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(300, 100)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Submit')
        button.clicked.connect(self.onclick)
        self.layout().addWidget(button)

    def onclick(self):
        self.close()
        message = "<font size = 5 color = gray > Rich Html Title </font> <br/><br/>The clickable link <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google.</a> The lower and upper case text."
        messagebox = QtGui.QMessageBox(QtGui.QMessageBox.Warning, "title", message, parent=self)
        messagebox.addButton("ResetRole Left Most", QtGui.QMessageBox.ResetRole)
        messagebox.addButton("ApplyRole Left", QtGui.QMessageBox.ApplyRole)
        messagebox.addButton("RejectRole Right", QtGui.QMessageBox.RejectRole)
        messagebox.addButton("NoRole Right Most", QtGui.QMessageBox.NoRole)
        exe = messagebox.exec_()
        print 'exe: %s  clickedButton: %s'%(exe, messagebox.clickedButton())

dialog = Dialog()
dialog.show()     
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Anyone know what is going on here with the button text padding on osx? It is not centered.